# How to simulate face up and face down in the iPhone simulator

Tags: cocoa-touch, opengl-es, ios-simulator

I am following a tutorial to make a 3D application that responds to changes in orientation. It even responds to orientation changes such as face up and face down. How can this be simulated in the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate Face up and Face down in the iOS simulator using the menu bar
Hardware -> Orientation ->[image]

Xcode 10.1

Answer (score 0):

I can share how I did it.
In didrotateFromInterfaceOrientation,check the width of navigationbar or toolbar .
Handle two cases,

if it is 320(Potrait)
{
//code
}
and

if it is 480(Landscpe)
{
//code
}

If you are going to design it for iPad,
Just compare for the widths of navigationbar for iPad.
It works for all the orientations

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't simulate face up or face down in the iOS Simulator.  This is still true in Xcode 6.  It's a great tool, but this is one of several features not available.  I found your question because I am also looking to simulate face up.